# Can I retrieve the lastInsertId from a bulk insert?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
INSERT INTO details (idactivity,user,hours,val,date) VALUES ('981','133','0','10500','2008-07-01'),('981','184','0','2750','2008-07-01'),('981','184','0','2750','2008-07-01')
```

(iddetails as details table PK)

Is there a way to get the 3 new iddetails and get them to the next bulk insert query?

```
INSERT INTO activity (idactivity,iddetails) VALUES('981',??),('981',??),('981',??)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, not in `mysql`.

Answer (score 6):

There is a detailed discussion of the [behavior of last_insert_id() with multi-row insert statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in the MySQL manual. Scroll down a little to the part with the red vertical bar beginning with the word "important".

Comment: link doesn't work anymore - here is the right one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Horen I just updated the link to the latest docs (5.6). I wonder why they deleted 5.4.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to do the initial inserts one at a time. MySQL's last_insert_id will just give you the id of the first element you insert with a multi-line insert statement like that. There may be issues if you have more than one process inserting lines at the same time.

However, (and I haven't verified this,) if you are using InnoDB tables, then the statement *should* be executed in an implicit transaction, so you *should* be able to assume that the ids generated were sequential.

Another way, again, if you have transactions, is to lock the table, and update it's AUTO_INCREMENT property manually. If you have 50 rows to insert, for instance, then bump it by 50. Then unlock the table, and insert your rows, explicitly using the ids you have reserved. You will need transations for this (or at least table locks) so that you don't read the AUTO_INCREMENT, and then have someone insert a new row before you update it.

Comment: "should be able to assume that the ids generated were sequential" - not without locking the table fist.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a datetime instead of just a date you could lookup the inserted id based on the user and the datetime values, but it is probably better so just not do a bulk insert if you need that data. Otherwise you end up running more queries anyway.

Comment: Not unique - CONNECTION_ID() would be better, but could still cause aliasing with persistent connections unless combined with a transaction flag.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a database field for a GUID and store a random one with each record.  then another query could extract the IDs

Answer (score -3):

Using SELECT last_insert_id( ) ; query you can get the last inserted id.