# Performance of VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, jdbc, batch-insert

The question is about `SQL` legacy code for `MySQL` database.

It is known, that when doing `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement `VALUES(col_name)` function [can be used](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to refer to column values from the INSERT portion instead of passing there exact values:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=VALUES(b), c=VALUES(c)
```

My legacy code contains a lot of huge inserts in parametrized style (they are used in batch-inserts):

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c, <...dozens of params...>) VALUES (?,?,?,<...dozens of values...>)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=?, c=?, <...dozens of params...>
```

The question is: would it increase performance of batch-inserts if I will change all these queries to use `VALUES(col_name)` function (in `UPDATE` portion)?

My queries are executed from java code using `jdbc` driver. So, what I guess, is that for long text values it should significantly reduce size of queries. What about `MySQL` it self? Would it really in general give me increasing of speed?

Comment: Yes for long values you might get a marginal benefit but this sort of effort is hardly worth it unless you are inserting a lot of records per minute

Comment: I'm inserting a lot of records in minute, indeed

Comment: guess it would then be worthy it since the change wont take up too much of your time.

Answer (score -1):

Batched inserts can may run 10 times as fast and one row at a time.  The reason for this is all the network, etc, overhead.

Another technique is to change from a single batched IODKU into two statements -- one to insert the new rows, one to do the updates.  (I don't know if that will run any faster.)  [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) is a discussion of the two steps, in the context of "normalization".

Another thing to note:  If there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` involved (not as one of the columns mentioned), then IODKU may "burn" ids for the cases where it does an 'update'.  That is, the IODKU (and `INSERT IGNORE` and a few others) get all the auto_incs that it *might* need, then proceeds to use the ones it *does* need and waste the others.

You get into "diminishing returns" if you try to insert more than a few hundred rows in a batch.  And you stress the rollback log.

Comment: You didn't read the question: **I'm already using BATCH instertion**. The question was about using `VALUES` function in update part.

Comment: Really? Why it's wrong? I'm using `Spring` `JDBC` batch inserts, so syntax is correct in that case

Comment: In MySQL, a batch insert looks like:  `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (11,22,33), ...`.  That is, N column names, plus M sets of N values to insert M rows into N columns.  Are you saying that Spring has a different syntax?

Comment: that's a really good question. It doesn't directly relate to my question and doesn't answer on it, but should be elaborated separately.

Comment: well I've looked into `MySQL` `PreparedStatement` sources and it has special method for conversion source SQL into batch one. So, yes, Spring internally calls `mysql` `jdbc` driver's `PrepatedStatement`'s implementation and use this correct batch syntax.

Comment: Do you have a hyperlink to the Spring syntax for batching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565481/how-to-do-multiple-inserts-in-database-using-spring-jdbc-template-batch

Comment: Thanks for that link.  However, none of the code there looks like your two IODKU examples.  I believe that the Spring code will build something like the IODKU example I gave -- multiple sets of 3 after `VALUES` and the '3' matches the number of columns before `VALUES` and in the `UPDATE` part.

Comment: You are right in part that `JDBC` driver itself (not Spring) will reformat initial SQL query and convert it to `mysql` batch style adding `on duplcates` to the end of query. If you will edit your answer and write about it, or if you will allow me to do so, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Since I am quite ignorant of JDBC and Spring, you should probably make the edit.