# How to handle Optimistic Locked item quantity update with concurrent users?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional, optimistic-locking

I have method which updates to Item quantity.

MyEntity has @Version annoted version property as long.

There is an item list endpoint `/items`
Also there is an item update endpoint `/item/update` (consider as product stock, buying an item)

So N concurrent users want's to update same item.

But there throws `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` that exception. While updating.

And also at this time, `/items` endpoint couldn't return data. Or waits user to return with too much latency.(If updating users count too much at this time it also gets an `exception timeout`).

So How can I handle that situation without any missing? (Can be good implementation )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JPA/Hibernate does not play nice with batch inserts when there is contention: whenever *any* exception is thrown in the context of a Hibernate session, you're out of luck.

See 13.2.3. Exception handling of: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-optimistic

Specifically:

> No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure
>   that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

In the past I have had to migrate JPA code to QueryDSL or fall back to raw SQL and JdbcTemplate (something like [How to do multiple inserts in database using spring JDBC Template batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565481/how-to-do-multiple-inserts-in-database-using-spring-jdbc-template-batch)).

Comment: By the way, why users couldn't get data while optimistic lock? I assume that's only write lock. I also use spring data.