# Codeigniter 2.1 - return ids after insert batch

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I return all IDs after insert_bunch? Function:

```
public function insert_slike($id, $slike, $folder, $polje, $tabela)
{
        $slike = explode(',', $slike);
        $i = 1;
        $data = array();
        foreach ($slike as $slk) {
            $this->img_upload_resize($slk, $folder);
            $data[] = array(
                $polje => $id,
                'path' => $slk
                );
            $i++;
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch($tabela, $data);
}
```

Comment: what will happen if some one run single insert along with batch insert? will get the right ID's? for example batch is running and ids from table comes like - 1,2,3,4,single insert here,6. Will it return - 1,2,3,4,6 or 1,2,3,4,5,6 on batch insert? making a reference to Alester answer, may be you know

Answer (score 18):

Here is an efficient method:

Since your records have result ID's, I'm going to assume they also auto-increment.

If this is the case, you do this and still use insert_batch.

Here is what you do:

**1.** You take a count of the items you are inserting:

```
$count = count($data);
```

**2.** Run your batch insert:

```
$this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
```

**3**.  Get the first inserted ID of your batch:

```
$first_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

**4.** Add the count (minus 1) to your insert ID to get the last records ID.

```
$last_id = $first_id + ($count-1);
```

There you go! You now have first and last ID's of your inserted records, and by extension, everything else in between.

**Note:**

A few people have asked what might happen if two batch inserts happen simultaneously; InnoDB will intelligently manage the ID's of the new rows to prevent the data intersecting, thus keeping this method valid.

Comment: What happens if there are 2 insert queries at the same time?

Comment: @machineaddict that what I'm thinking for. What happens when 2 users insert two queries at the same time. Help?

Comment: For 2 simple queries, I think they get queued. But what happens if 2 batch insert queries intersect at the same time?

Comment: To my knowledge, innoDB manages the distribution of data properly to prevent data intersecting.

Comment: @Alastor what will happen if some one run single insert along with batch insert? will get the right ID's? for example batch is running and ids from table comes like - 1,2,3,4,single insert here,6. 
Will it return - 1,2,3,4,6 or 1,2,3,4,5,6 on batch insert?

Comment: @LovepreetSinghBatth As insert_batch() runs a single INSERT query, this is up to the database engine in question, however as I understand it (for the InnoDB engine at least) the ID's of the batch insert are 'booked' away for the batch insert, and the single insert should then be provided an ID that would come after the pre-computed batch IDs.

Comment: Yeah, here is the source of it, as Platinum said, the default setting of auto-inc is locked, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes

Answer (score 3):

This topic with respect to MySQL has been previously discussed:

[How can I Insert many rows into a MySQL table and return the new IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-get-ids-back)

In CodeIgniter, using `$this->db->insert_id()` will return only id of the first insert.

If I were doing this, I would open a transaction and do the inserts one at at time, storing the id after each insert.

Comment: It's better than the others.

Comment: How is it better? Individual inserts is a ridiculously inefficient and slow method.

Comment: Yep, performance wise is to batch insert, take the first id and add it manually trough numbers of datas since InnoDB lock auto-inc (default setting). src: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes

Answer (score 0):

1.Create own ID instead of auto-generated ones.

2.Insert with the id you have genereated

3.Have a array of inserted ID

4.Return the array of inserted ID

Answer (score 0):

insert_batch() function return only first id of your batch. 
use insert() function in for loop to get all id's.

```
public function insert_slike($id, $slike, $folder, $polje, $tabela)
{
    $slike = explode(',', $slike);
    $data = array();
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($slike as $slk) {
        $this->img_upload_resize($slk, $folder);
        $data = array(
             $polje => $id,
             'path' => $slk
             );
        $this->db->insert($tabela, $data);
        $ids[]=$this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you expand this answer to provide example usage?

Comment: public function insert_slike($id, $slike, $folder, $polje, $tabela)
{
    $slike = explode(',', $slike);
    $data = array();
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($slike as $slk) {
        $this->img_upload_resize($slk, $folder);
        $data = array(
             $polje => $id,
             'path' => $slk
             );
        $this->db->insert($tabela, $data);
        $ids[]=$this->db->insert_id();
    }
}