# How to get all inserted records ids in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to get all inserted records ids in codeigniter ?? I am using insert_batch function in for inserting multiple records but codeigniter $this->db->insert_id() function returns only last record id.
//But i need all inserted records ids. If any one has idea please help.

```
//In codeigniter this function returns only last inserted record id.

function insertStudent(){

    $data[] = array('firstname'=>'firstname1','lastname'=>'lastname1');

    $data[] = array('firstname'=>'firstname2','lastname'=>'lastname2');

    $result = $this->db->insert_batch( 'student', $data );

    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

Comment: your id is auto incremented?

Comment: yes in student table i have id field that is (primary key and auto-increment)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685080/codeigniter-2-1-return-ids-after-insert-batch

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using first id and count.

1. Get count of data that you are inserting. (e.g. 2 in your example)
2. Get first insert id by `$this->db->insert_id()` (e.g. say 30)
3. Now get last insert recorded id by = `first record id - (count - 1)` (e.g. 30 + (2-1) = 31)

Now you can query to get data between id's 30 and 31.

Comment: yes this is last approach.But is there any function which returns all inserted records ids in codeigniter ? or can we  modify insert_id() function for return multiple ids.

Comment: you can modify but that's not recommended to hack into core files.

Comment: Simple enough, but if there's any possibility at all that you may end up having your code running on top of a multi-master database scheme, it'll not work as expected as autoincremented fields will be offset and not sequential

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Agreed. Considering generic scenario here it won't cause any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must have the insert_id for each inserted row, the simplest most failproof way would be to loop multiple inserts rather than making one big fat insert.

Looping through multiple inserts will allow you to get all insert_ids. It will also allow you to not loose all the data if one of the rows fails inserting and the database rejects them all because of that.

Comment: yes it will work but. insert query inside loop not good for performance.

Comment: that has a lot of "ifs", actually. Unless you're running your database server close to capacity and making several thousand inserts on each pass, the time difference and resource impact difference is negligible. There's no nirvana in this, there will always be trade-offs. Making multiple inserts may have some downsides but it's not evil if done correctly.  Up until recently, I managed a small database server which was updated several times a minute with around 6000 inserts on each pass. Never went over 500ms of processing time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient method:

Since your records have result ID's, I'm going to assume they also auto-increment.

If this is the case, you do this and still use `insert_batch`.

Here is what you do:

1. You take a count of the items you are inserting:

   ```
   $count = count($data);
   ```
2. Run your batch insert:

   ```
   $this->db->insert_batch('student', $data);
   ```
3. Get the first inserted ID of your batch:

   ```
   $first_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   ```
4. Add the count (minus 1) to your insert ID to get the last records ID.

   ```
   $last_id = $first_id + ($count-1);
   ```

There you go! You now have first and last ID's of your inserted records, and by extension, everything else in between.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution is to update the DB_driver.php.

- From

```php
public function is_write_type($sql)
{
  return (bool) (preg_match('/^\s*"?(SET|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|REPLACE|CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|LOAD|COPY|ALTER|RENAME|GRANT|REVOKE|LOCK|UNLOCK|REINDEX)\s+/i', $sql);
}
```

- To:

```php
public function is_write_type($sql)
{
  return (bool) (preg_match('/^\s*"?(SET|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|REPLACE|CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|LOAD|COPY|ALTER|RENAME|GRANT|REVOKE|LOCK|UNLOCK|REINDEX)\s+/i', $sql) && !preg_match('/ RETURNING /i', $sql));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The really safest way is:

1. Add a column `code` in your table.
2. Create a code before batch inserting `[id session user]-[current time stamp]` should be enough.
3. Batch insert all elements with that code into `code` column
4. Query a `Select` searching for that code, you will have all elements inserted at batch insert

Answer (score -1):

```
function insertStudent(){

    $data[] = array('firstname'=>'firstname1','lastname'=>'lastname1');

    $data[] = array('firstname'=>'firstname2','lastname'=>'lastname2');

    $result = $this->db->insert_batch( 'student', $data );

    $a= $this->db->get('student');
    $data = $a->result_array();
    echo($data[0]['id']);

}
```

Hope So this will help you.