# insert_batch does not return last insert id

Tags: codeigniter

```
    //my model
public function saveRecords($table,$data)
   {
       $data = $this->db2->insert_batch($table, $data);
        echo $first_id = $this->db->insert_id();
       return $data;
   }
```

//my controller
   public function save($table,$data)
   {`enter code here`
      $test = $this->DBmodel->saveRecords('agentconnect',$data);
   }

Comment: insert_batch does not return insert_id. if you use insert_id it will return id of first insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter 2.1 - return ids after insert batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685080/codeigniter-2-1-return-ids-after-insert-batch)

Answer (score 0):

insert_batch always return the first insert id.

use this -

```
public function saveRecords($table,$data)
 {
       foreach ($data as $data1) 
       {
         $this->db->insert($table,$data1);
         $id[]=$this->db->insert_id();
       }
       return $id;
 }
```