# How to detect inserted ids on "insert ignore" statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Now,do nothing when "on duplicate key update".
So,

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1 c1 VALUES(...,...,...);
```

The last_insert_id is only one id at most.

Then how to detect multi inserted ids on "insert ignore" statement?

Answer (score 0):

**Using LAST_INSERT_ID()**

There is no way that I'm aware of that a regular bulk `INSERT` can return more than one `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. It will always return the ID of the first record inserted for that bulk INSERT statement.

You can view the documentation on it which explains that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client.

Emphasis on the *first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column*. So as described the first successful row inserted via a bulk `INSERT` will be the return value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

**Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and ROW_COUNT() with InnoDB**

There is an alternate solution [as posted by Dag Sondre Hansen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-get-ids-back) which may suit your needs. It does presume your tables/database use InnoDB though.

> If you are using InnoDB on a recent version of MySQL, you can get the
>   list of IDs using LAST_INSERT_ID() and ROW_COUNT().
>
> InnoDB guarantees sequential numbers for AUTO INCREMENT when doing
>   bulk inserts, provided innodb_autoinc_lock_mode is set to 0
>   (traditional) or 1 (consecutive). Consequently you can get the first
>   ID from LAST_INSERT_ID() and the last by adding ROW_COUNT()-1.

Just make sure you do this on the same connection, directly after your `INSERT` statement or you won't get the results you're expecting.