# Mysql Batch insert doesn't update LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I've found an interesting solution to a problem I have with the 1st answer on this StackOverflow question: [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225804/mysql-batch-insert-on-multiple-tables-with-last-insert-id)
The problem is that it doesn't work as I expected. If my table is empty, the first bulk insert work correctly but LAST_INSERT_ID returns 1 when the bulk has inserted 100 lines. If I change it and put 100 simple Insert it works. autoinc_loc_mode is set to 1.

Is there a setting to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is the expected behavior; [from MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
>   row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce
>   easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.

Comment: Oh. you are basically telling me that the linked answer is written upside-down. I should do a last_insert_id()+n instead of -n

Comment: @mobinoob that depends on what you want to do with last_insert_id() (you only said you had a problem and found a solution). You usually need last_insert_id if you want to access the data you just inserted. last_insert_id()+n isn't of much use most of the time - do you e.g. want to know max(id)?

Comment: @Solarflare sorry, you have to check the linked question. I have to do something similar. A java program build the inserts. The last_insert_id is used on that solution as a known id that is deincremented for each step. Imagine a foreach() loop that build those two bulk insert. The solution is either do X insert or transform it to a last_insert_id + N.

Comment: @Solarflare tldr; version of what i do: fetch data from internet and then put it on my db with two inserts, one for the item, and one for the relation item-category.