# get ids of multiple inserts in mysql...is order guaranteed?

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting multiple rows like so:

```
INSERT INTO table (col_a,col_b) VALUES (111,'example'),
    (222,'another example'),(333,'blah'),(444,'another blah'),(555,'aldksjf')
```

Neither `col_a` or `col_b` are primary keys. My primary key has an `auto_increment` on it, let's call it `table_id`.

I've come across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-return-the-new-ids) which indicates that I can use `LAST_INSERT_ID` and `ROW_COUNT` to determine the `table_id` of my previous inserts.

My question is order guaranteed? Specifically, if `LAST_INSERT_ID` is 15 is 15 guaranteed to have values `(111,'example')` and will table_id 18 guaranteed to have `(444,'another blah')`? Or does it simply mean that the 5 inserted rows will have ids 15 - 19 but not necessarily in the order of the values section of my statement.

Comment: This topic may help you a bit..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-return-the-new-ids?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @venkat Isn't that the link in their question?

Comment: @Venkat I saw that already and its already listed in my question. I am asking about whether the inserted rows are guaranteed to match the order of the values section of my statement, or whether it guarantees ids will be 15-19, but not necessarily in the order of the values section of my statement