# How can I get all inserted ids in mysql using node module in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, npm, node-mysql

I have table

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |
| 2 | two |

I want to insert multiple data in this table with

```
const query = `INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES("three"), ("four")`;
```

now I used this with any npm module like:

```
const result = await SQL.query(query);
```

then it returns only 4 but I want [3,4] (auto incremented Id) (and wants all new inserted data's id like 3 and four currently it returns only 4) how can I archive this

Comment: Don't you know `ref` in advance when putting it into DB?

Comment: Sorry @Justinas ref is actually primary id of table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Insert many rows into a MySQL table and return the new IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-return-the-new-ids)