# How to get list of created/updated indexes from INSERT INTO with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in SP [MySQL 8.0.36]

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

How does one get a list of the record IDs created or updated when an INSERT INTO with ON DUPLICATE KEY is used - within the very stored procedure that executes the INSERT?

For example, such an action could update records 5,23,91, and create 92,93,94,95.

ROW_COUNT() and LAST_INSERT_ID() isn't enough to do this, and I don't see a function available to MySQL that presents the same as mysql_affected_rows().

So how can I get a list of the row IDs that were added and updated with this scenario?

Comment: i ca not understand what you are asking for

Comment: For what do you need the IDs for updated **and** inserted rows? For inserted rows, there are other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333524/how-can-i-insert-many-rows-into-a-mysql-table-and-return-the-new-ids, but why do you need these ids at the same time?

Comment: @Progman because the SP is a proxy SP for our backend system and they want to know what record IDs were either created or updated.

Comment: @Floobinator What is "SP"?

Comment: @Progman Apologies - Stored Procedure.

Comment: Mysql does not support the returning clause for any of the data modification sql statements, so you would have to use select statements before the insert ... on duplicate key update to confirm what the results will be.

Comment: @Shadow thank you for confirming; I figured this might be the case, but wanted to verify. If you want to throw together a quick answer encapsulating your comment, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may obtain needed data using user-defined variables and triggers.

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT
);
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ins -- save id of the inserted row
AFTER INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
SET @inserted := CONCAT_WS(',', @inserted, NEW.id);
CREATE TRIGGER tr_upd -- save id of the updated row
AFTER UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
SET @updated := CONCAT_WS(',', @updated, NEW.id);
```

```
-- clear user-defined variables which will collect the list of effected rows
SET @inserted := NULL;
SET @updated := NULL;
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,1),    -- explicit insert
(NULL,2), -- autogenerated insert
(NULL,3), -- autogenerated insert
(2,4),    -- update
(1,5),    -- update
(2,6),    -- update
(NULL,7), -- autogenerated insert
(5,8),    -- explicit insert
(3,9)     -- update
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val = VALUES(val);
SELECT * FROM test;
-- see the lists of inserted/updated row's id values
SELECT @inserted, @updated;
```

> ```
> Records: 9  Duplicates: 4  Warnings: 1
> ```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

| @inserted | @updated |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3,4,5 | 2,1,2,3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/67ImP_qd)